# VBA Excel: Type value in <input> tag (using Id attribute)

Tags: excel, vba, getelementbyid

How can I type a value from a cell into an  tag using Id attribute?

I have phew  tags in a webpage (see example below):

```
<input id="myId" type="text" value= "2>
```

I have the following code to search all  tags and when it finds the  tag with specific Id, I want to type the new value.

```
Set objInputCollection = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")

countInputObjects = 0
Do While countInputObjects < objInputCollection.Length

    Select Case objInputCollection(countInputObjects).ID

        Case "myId"
            ' Set value
            objInputCollection(countInputObjects).Value = Sheets("MySheet").Range("D15").Value

        Case "myID_2"
            ' Set "Range" value
            objInputCollection(countInputObjects).Value = Sheets("MySheet").Range("D10").Value

    End Select

    countInputObjects = countInputObjects + 1

Loop
```

My code is not working and does not go into any "Case".

Comment: `IE.Document.getElementById("myId")` will give you the specific input you want.

Comment: When I use that
IE.Document.getElementById("myId").Value = 2 
it returns a Run-time error '424': Object required

Comment: Then likely there's no element with that id.

Comment: When I check the webpage code source i can find the element.

Comment: Can't really suggest anything without seeing the URL or the HTML source and/or the rest of your code.

Comment: The webpage is only available if you are in the same network. I cannot share the URL.

Comment: Is it possible the page is not fully-loaded when your code runs?  Try putting a break in your code and waiting a few seconds before running the rest of the lines.

Comment: Maybe. The input tags refer to DatePicker and it is hidden when the page loads. You need to click an icon to popup the DatePicker.

Although Im selecting a value from a <select> tag in DatePicker without clicking on it.

I tested like you said and it worked. It seems I need to click on the icon first to popup the datepicker.